# Return a value according to two variable

Tags: php, variables

I want to return a value based on the content of two variables.
Let me explain better, I have three variables:

```
$var1 = 2; // This variable can change from 1 to 10 (based on the value in the database)
$var2 = 1; // This variable can have two values: 0 and 1 (based on the value in the database)

$result = ''; // This variable have a value based on the content of the two variables
```

I take two values ​​from two different column of the Database ($var1 and $var2) and I have $result, a variable that have a value based on the content of $var1 and $var2

This can be done easily, making 20 conditions, like this:

```
if ($var1 == 1 && $var == 0) $result = 'good morning';
if ($var1 == 1 && $var == 1) $result = 'hello';
if ($var1 == 2 && $var == 0) $result = 'never';
```

But my question is: there is a way for write this piece of code more easily, easy to read and more manageable?

**PS**: $result have completely different values, concatenation not needed in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, it's only an example, $result have completely different values.

Comment: @Keaire - You should update your question to reflect that.

Comment: Then show us your real code/example. If there is no pattern behind it you can't do anything

Comment: So what is the rule for combining the values?

Comment: I take two values ​​from two different column of the Database ($var1 and $var2) and I have $result, a variable that have a value based on the content of $var1 and $var2.

Comment: I edited the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All other answers are good, I just want to add another possibility:

Store your `result`'s values into an array, and call/search it like this:

```
$data[1][0] = 'good morning';
$data[1][1] = 'hello';
$data[2][0] = 'never';
//$data[x][y] = 'result of $var1=x and $var2=y';

// if exists a combination
if (isset($data[$var1][$var2])) {
    // get the value
    $result = $data[$var1][$var2];
}
```

Comment: I like also Niet the Dark Absol answer, but I think this is the best way to do it, it's shorter to write and more manageable. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think this might be a more manageable version of your code:

```
switch([$var1,$var2]) {
    case [0,0]:
        // code
        break;
    case [0,1]:
        // code
        break;
    // ...
    default:
        // pairing wasn't defined
}
```

Without knowing the exact nature of `$var1` and `$var2`, nor the significance of `$result`, I can't really help more, but this should be a good start.

Comment: A matrix of values might also work. Build the matrix of values and then just get that index. `$result = 'value' . $m[$var1][$var2];`

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = 'value' . $var1 . '.' . $var2;
```

Comment: It's only an example, $result have completely different values.

Comment: @Keaire In that case, you should be clearer in your question.

Comment: @Keaire Well.. But it matchs your requirements: $var1 (0 up to10) and $var2 (0 up to 1)

Answer (score 0):

Well, many ways!

Following your piece of code you can build the string:

```
$result = "$var1" . "." . "$var2";
```

using the "value-to-string" effect.

You can also return an array:

```
$result = array("var1" => $var1, "var2" => $var2);
```

and access each part with $res["var1"/"var2"].

Comment: I will never understand why people do `"$var" . "."` instead of `$var . "."`

Comment: @samlev: or `"$var1.$var2"`

Comment: just because here it seems to be a beginner on PHP and − in my opinion − " means 'string' and each element is distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if concat'ing this is what you're looking for. If it's not, then `switch()` might be the way to go:

```
<?php
switch(true){
    case ($var1 == 1 && $var == 0):
        $result = 'value1.0';
        break; 
    case ($var1 == 1 && $var == 1):
        $result = 'value1.1';
        break;
    case ($var1 == 2 && $var == 0):
        $result = 'value2.0'
        break;
    default:
        $result = 'value0.0';
}
?>
```

Another options, after your edit, would be to make a Matrix:

```
$m = array();

$m[1] = array(0 => 'good morning', 1 => 'hello');
$m[2] = array(0 => 'never');

$result = isset($m[$var1][$var2])?$m[$var1][$var2]:""; // Or false if you prefer
```